# Parsing XML in Python to populate common values

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, soap-client

After trying to traverse values for my XML Payload, i am hitting dead-end.

I have a SOAP API XML response, which has common value's coming inside main record. I am able to extract records, but not able to populate common value's.

Can someone please guide me on an approach. Want to populate Field id="3" and "4" to all the records under the nest which is levelId="202".

Sharing my Current code below and full API output can be found at -> [Sample API Response](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/a-y-u-1/xml_Resp/main/sample_resp.txt).

```
<Record contentId="28503182" levelId="202" levelGuid="34df2128-c36c-4017-b6c3-de09dbb8bd0b" moduleId="400" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="28503182" levelId="202" levelGuid="34df2128-c36c-4017-b6c3-de09dbb8bd0b" moduleId="400" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="28739688" levelId="62" levelGuid="b08s5b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">69141</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Priviion</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="b085bs230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">69155</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Accedress</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="b08d5b230-es0f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">8548</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Apss</Field>
        </Record>   
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="bss5b230-es0f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">848</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Bions</Field>
        </Record>           
        <Field id="3" guid="422cdb8e-1013-454a-b048-3cc630163a6e" type="9">
            <Reference id="28151495">Class 2</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="4" guid="7bcacb1c-4e3f-4598-a904-e2e0ae2be97d" type="1">6589</Field>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Code as of now:

```
    # Extract data from XML and create a list of dictionaries
    records = []
    for record in root.findall('Record'):
        record_data = {}
        for field in record.findall('Field'):
            field_id = int(field.get('id'))
            if field_id in column_order:
                record_data[field_id] = field.text
        records.append(record_data)

    # Create a DataFrame from the records
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)

    # Reorder the columns based on the desired order
    df = df[column_order]

    # Save DataFrame to a CSV file with encoded characters
    df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

The current logic is able to extract values for id = 1 and 2, populates id 3 and 4 to the first record instead of all the records in that group

Current output looks like

```
ID,Name,Class,Code
68332,abc,Class 1,165664
68333,someothername,
69141,Priviion,Class 2,6589
69155,Accedress,
8548,Apss,
848,Bions,
```

instead of

```
ID,Name,Class,Code
68332,abc,Class 1,165664
68333,someothername,Class 1,165664
69141,Priviion,Class 2,6589
69155,Accedress,Class 2,6589
8548,Apss,Class 2,6589
848,Bions,Class 2,6589
```

Comment: The sample response, as well as the response you posted on github, are not well-formed xml. Can you recheck and fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags in your xmls seems to be a little off. From what I could understand, I combined both. Here I have used `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `numpy` to create DataFrame. You may use [other than numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


xml_text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records count="5">
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="1" guid="85a5f539-fd41-4682-bda3-588bdcdacca8" name="ID" alias="S_ID" />
            <FieldDefinition id="2" guid="b2bf7611-6006-443c-9872-3e8067255104" name="Name" alias="Name_Updated" />
            <FieldDefinition id="3" guid="b012f524-fb9c-44e2-88b0-904407f19ad0" name="Class" alias="common_class" />
            <FieldDefinition id="4" guid="b012f524-fb9c-44e2-88b0-904407f19ad0" name="Code" alias="code" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="202" guid="34df2128-c36c-4017-b6c3-de09dbb8bd0b" count="1746" />
        <LevelCount id="62" guid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" count="9809" />
    </LevelCounts>
    <Record contentId="28111640" levelId="202" levelGuid="34df2128-c36c-4017-b6c3-de09dbb8bd0b" moduleId="400" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="28618177" levelId="62" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">68332</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">abc</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="28618183" levelId="62" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">68333</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">someothername</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="3" guid="422cdb8e-1013-454a-b048-3cc630163a6e" type="9">
            <Reference id="28151495">Class 1</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="4" guid="7bcacb1c-4e3f-4598-a904-e2e0ae2be97d" type="1">165664</Field>
    </Record>
    
    <Record contentId="28503182" levelId="202" levelGuid="34df2128-c36c-4017-b6c3-de09dbb8bd0b" moduleId="400" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="28739688" levelId="62" levelGuid="b08s5b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">69141</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Priviion</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="b085bs230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">69155</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Accedress</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="b08d5b230-es0f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">8548</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Apss</Field>
        </Record>   
        <Record contentId="28739790" levelId="62" levelGuid="bss5b230-es0f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
            <Field id="1" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">848</Field>
            <Field id="2" guid="43dddeeb-052f-4f29-a179-28e3f9406852" type="1">Bions</Field>
        </Record>           
        <Field id="3" guid="422cdb8e-1013-454a-b048-3cc630163a6e" type="9">
            <Reference id="28151495">Class 2</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="4" guid="7bcacb1c-4e3f-4598-a904-e2e0ae2be97d" type="1">6589</Field>
    </Record>
</Records>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
records = []
# searching for all <Record> in <Records> which is also root
for record in root.findall('Record'):
    # searching for common class and code in <Record>
    common_class = record.find('.//Field[@id="3"]//Reference').text
    code = record.find('.//Field[@id="4"]').text
    # searching for id and name in <Record> inside <Record>
    for r in record.findall('Record'):
        id = r.find('.//Field[@id="1"]').text
        name = r.find('.//Field[@id="2"]').text
        # appending to records
        records.append([id, name, common_class, code])
# creating dataframe with records list and columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(records), columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Class', 'Code'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      ID           Name    Class    Code
0  68332            abc  Class 1  165664
1  68333  someothername  Class 1  165664
2  69141       Priviion  Class 2    6589
3  69155      Accedress  Class 2    6589
4   8548           Apss  Class 2    6589
5    848          Bions  Class 2    6589
```